# Java Thread Pool that gets the last task added to the BlockingQueue and discard the others

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, threadpool

I want a thread pool with a single thread but with a peculiar behavior for the `BlockingQueue`:

If I add a job to the queue and then add another job (making the queue hold two jobs), I want the thread to ignore the first job added and get the last one. So, everytime the thread gets a task from the queue, I want it to get the last job added to the queue and discard the others.

Is there any default `BlockingQueue` with this behavior? What would be the best strategy to achieve this? Should I implement my own `BlockingQueue`? If yes, from which `BlockingQueue` should I start from?

My initial idea was to create a bounded blocking queue with capacity for only one task, but that when it's full and receives another task, it swaps the tasks discarding the task that was added earlier. Do I make sense?

Comment: How about a [BlockingDequeue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingDeque.html) Then you can poll from the tail and get the last in.

Comment: @matt The older tasks must be discarded. I can't process them once I have processed a newer task. Also, I don't want to manually poll them, I want to use a thread pool so I don't need to worry about the polling.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are on the right track with creating a bounded blocking queue with capacity for only one task. Additionally, configure your `ThreadPoolExecutor` with a [`DiscardOldestPolicy`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.DiscardOldestPolicy.html). Thus, whenever a second task is submitted, it doesn’t fit into the queue and according to the policy the older one gets discarded.

Compare with the constructor [`ThreadPoolExecutor(int, int, long, TimeUnit, BlockingQueue, RejectedExecutionHandler)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#ThreadPoolExecutor-int-int-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue-java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionHandler-)

Comment: This looks promising! Thanks, I'll have a look at it right now. What kind of `BlockingQueue` should I use, though? Or as long as it's bounded with capacity of 1 it doesn't matter the kind?

Comment: I think it doesn’t matter, but since `ArrayBlockingQueue` has the simplest structure, I would use it whenever I want a fixed capacity of one.

Comment: Just what I thought. This is the thread pool I'll be using for my tests: `new ThreadPoolExecutor(1, 1, 0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, new ArrayBlockingQueue<Runnable>(1), new ThreadPoolExecutor.DiscardOldestPolicy())`

Answer (score 1):

I would use a an atomic variable.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReference.html

Example:

```
AtomicReference<X> task_;
//Pop
public X pop() { return task_.getAndSet(NULL); }
//Push
public X push (X val) { return task_.getAndSet(val); }
```

It is also wait-free in design.

Comment: The issue with this is your consumer can pull null, where a blocking queue the consumer just waits until something is there.

Comment: But then I would have to implement my own polling strategy instead of using it from Java's thread pool implementation (i.e. having my thread checking whether there is a new task in my `AtomicReference` that was not processed yet and must be processed), right?

Comment: I forgot the blocking aspect, I could just wrap it in a while loop... but there is probably a better using notify/signal mechanisms